# Should there be a question about the collapse of the Twin Towers?

Tags: discussion

Such a question already exists.

[Is there anything inexplicable about how the WTC Twin Towers collapsed?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2108/56774)

However, this question is marked as a duplicate with the following note from the OP.

> ### NEXT DAY...
>
> I don't have the rep to delete my own question here. But this other question, although primarily about Building 7, has very good answers covering everything I wanted to know. My apologies if anyone feels I have wasted their time asking again.

The cited duplicate, however, *cannot* address some of the most common claims regarding the Twin Towers.

- For example, many claim that the top-down collapse violates Newton's third law.
- Similarly, it is often claimed that the visibly rotating top floors of the South Tower should have fallen off and arrested the progressive collapse, as per Newton's first law.
- Moreover, sideways ejections of large debris is often claimed to not be consistant with a gravitational collapse ("gravity acts vertically, not laterally")

These claims cannot be addressed in an answer about Building 7, as they do not apply to Building 7.

Should this question be reopened? Should it be rephrased? Or should a new question be asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question that you linked is not suitable for our site for a number of reasons.

For starters, the question is extremely broad and not acceptable.

From reading the question, the primary focus seems to be on the (now memetic) idea that "Jet Fuel Can't Melt Steel Beams.  Which in addition to having been answered multiple times on multiple sites throughout the internet, has been asked in a couple different forms on this very website.

The lack of sources provided by the OP in the question you asked also makes this a close reason.  Just citing Zeitgeist: The Movie isn't a source.  Ignoring the other issues in this question, we would require, at a bare minimum, a link to the scene in question.  This is also ignoring the fact that Zeitgeist has been examined and debunked so many times on the internet already that any answer would most likely just reference those pages that could be found via a simple internet search.

---

I'd suggest that you start by browsing this list.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/9-11

Then, if you have a ***specific*** claim with a ***notable source*** that isn't answered in one of those questions, then you should ask a question.

---